# Regular expression: Get TeX commands

Tags: php, regex, tex

I have a string like:

```
$str = "\textaolig 3 \texthtbardotlessjvar  \textrthooklong
    B \textbenttailyogh ; \textinvomega q \textscaolig
    . \textbktailgamma p \textinvsca r \textscdelta
    D \textctinvglotstop ! \textinvscripta s \textscf
    2 \textctjvar I \textlfishhookrlig t \textsck";
```

And I wanna get all the TeX commands (\textaolig etc.) with a regular expression. I tried:

```
\\([[a-z]\s]+)
```

But with no luck. Can someone help me out?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to enclose your string with single quotes because when using double quotes if you use a backslash it will try to escape a character, which isn't your case.

Secondly, you have to use `\\\\` to match a backslash.

<strike>I don't know about TeX commands, but I've tried to match `[\w\s\.;]+` so correct it if needed:</strike>

```
$str = '\textaolig 3 \texthtbardotlessjvar \textrthooklong
    B \textbenttailyogh ; \textinvomega q \textscaolig
    . \textbktailgamma p \textinvsca r \textscdelta
    D \textctinvglotstop ! \textinvscripta s \textscf
    2 \textctjvar I \textlfishhookrlig t \textsck';
    preg_match_all('/\\\\(?P<tex>\w+)/s', $str, $m);

    var_dump($m["tex"]);
```

Comment: The TeX commands are the commands like \textaolig. With your help, i finally got it right.
     preg_match_all('/\\\\([\w]+)/s', $str, $m);
did the job. Thank you very much.